# Crystal Reports default value for parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm attempting to make the parameters for a Crystal Report more user-friendly for a client, who has requested that they be able to have the default values for a Start and End date parameter be the first and last day of the previous month.

I know how to use either a formula in CR or a stored procedure to produce these values, but I want to know if a variable can be used in the 'Default Value' setting for a parameter, or if it only allows for static entries. Does anyone know? Right now the user can set the date parameters to null and the stored procedure generates the data for the previous month on its own, but I thought it'd be nice if the date parameters actually displayed the dates that were being used as defaults. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, Try below process:

1. Create a parameter `?date` with String datatype and take static and write two default strings as below:

First day of previous month
Last day of Previous month

2. Now go to `record selection formula` and write below code:

   if ({?date}="First day of previous month") then
   table.date=DateSerial(year(currentdate),Month(Currentdate)-1,1)
   else if ({?date}="Last day of previous month")
   then 
   table.date=Cdate(DateAdd("d",-1,DateSerial(year(currentdate),Month(Currentdate),1)))